# Can I reference nested object array properties dynamically?

Tags: javascript

I have   array like this

```
var object_ = [
  {
      "name":"Akshay"
  }
];
```

```
var object_keys = "[0]['other_data']";
```

Correct way is like this to add the sub data

```
object_[0]['other_data'] = {
"age":20,
"Sex": "male"
}
```

My question is Can i do something like this ?

```
object_[object_keys] = {
"age":20,
"Sex": "male"
}
```

Comment: Your `object_` is an array, not an object

Comment: Also that `object_` initializer is a syntax error.

Comment: Please take the [tour] so you know how to use this site. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Lodash's [`_.set`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set) method achieves this:

```js
var object_ = [{
  "name": "Akshay"
}];

_.set(object_, "[0]['other_data']", {
  "age": 20,
  "Sex": "male"
})

console.log(object_)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks but there is error in the code

Comment: @AkshayDhiman What error?

Comment: {
  "message": "ReferenceError: _ is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 16,
  "colno": 1
}

Comment: @AkshayDhiman I'm not getting this error on my side. I've switched the CDN. Try again.

Comment: You shouldn't need to load an entire library for this. That's not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

One strategy might be to store your keys in an array rather than a string, and reference each key by index:

```js
let object_ = [{
  "name": "Akshay"
}];
const object_keys = [0, 'other_data'];

object_[object_keys[0]][object_keys[1]] = {
  "age": 20,
  "Sex": "male"
};

console.log(object_);
```

Comment: object_keys[0]][object_keys[1] --> Can we do this part with code instead typing the keys

Comment: That _is_ code. I don't understand. You can write a function that takes the object array and the keys array and merges them just like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using `[0, 'other_data']` instead of `"[0]['other_data']"` you can easily write a generic function that takes an object, key array and a value. Then sets the value based on the given key array (aka key path).

```js
function setValue(object, keys, value) {
  if (!keys.length) return;  // keys is empty
  
  // Create a shallow copy of `keys`. Mutating the `object` parameter
  // is intended, mutating the `keys` parameter is not.
  keys = Array.from(keys);
  
  const lastKey  = keys.pop(); 
  const lastNode = keys.reduce((node, key) => node[key], object);
  
  lastNode[lastKey] = value;
}

var object_ = [
  {
      "name":"Akshay"
  }
];

var object_keys = [0, 'other_data'];

setValue(object_, object_keys, {
  "age": 20,
  "Sex": "male",
});

console.log(object_);
```